# How can we get output in standard numeric format for expr command on solaris

Tags: format, standards, numeric

I am expecting the output of following command as `03` not `3`:

```
$expr 01 + 02

3
```

Do have any alternate way to get o/p like 01, 02...09

(Running command on Solaris8)